# Proper usage of @Html.DropDownListfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this textbox :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
```

Model.Type is a string. I want to change this to DropDownList for that type. I want to handle list elements on View, I don't want to use a class for that.
My failed attempt is this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Type, 
 new List<SelectListItem>
{
  new SelectListItem {"Horror"},
  new SelectListItem {"Fiction"},
  new SelectListItem {"Romance"},
})
```

How can I use DropDownListFor correctly in this case? Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the property name you're assigning in the initializer.  `new SelectListItem { Text = "Horror"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. This

```
new SelectListItem {"Horror"}
```

makes no sense.

it should be

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Horror", Value = "Horror" }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's required?  Value should be optional, since the browser will submit the text if there is no value.

Comment: I find it's best to be explicit. Either way, what the OP has posted won't compile as it is.

Comment: Yes, because there is no property assignment in the initializer, good point.